# Trouble with the GetPoint command Tkz-Euclide-Euclide

Tags: tkz-euclide

I am trying to make a simple circle with a radius marked and a diameter but I can't seem to use the GetPoint to workouts not sure what I am doing wrong

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{diagram}

    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(-3,0){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(3,0){E}
        \tkzInterLC(O,D)(O,A) \tkzGetPoint{B}
        \tkzInterLC(O,E)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
            \tkzDrawCircles(O,A)
                \tkzLabelPoint[left](O){$O$}
                \tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$A$}
                \tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
                \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
                    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray,opacity=0.5](O,A,B,C)
                        \tkzDrawSegment[red](O,A)
                        \tkzDrawSegment[blue](B,C)
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

And am I just making a simple problem more complicated than it needs to be? I can do this with tikz but I am trying to get to grips with Tkz-Euclide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1)

```
\tkzInterLC(O,D)(O,A) \tkzGetPoints{B}{C}
```

Solution 2)

```
 \tkzInterLC(O,D)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{B}
 \tkzInterLC(O,E)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
```

etc... you have other possibilities with `\tkzGetFirstPoint`

You need to look at the documentation about "intersection" to choice the good solution

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
   \tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
   \tkzDefPoint(-3,0){D}
   \tkzDefPoint(3,0){E}
   \tkzInterLC(O,D)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{B}
   \tkzInterLC(O,E)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
   \tkzDrawCircles(O,A)
   \tkzLabelPoint[left](O){$O$}
   \tkzLabelPoint[right](A){$A$}
   \tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}
   \tkzLabelPoint[right](C){$C$}
   \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray,opacity=0.5](O,A,B,C)
   \tkzDrawSegment[red](O,A)
   \tkzDrawSegment[blue](B,C)
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]